# How to check lists for changes

Tags: python, google-api-client, python-datetime

I was experimenting with a google Calendar API for python, and I want to check every five seconds for a new event addition to the calendar. I know to set it as an old list and then compare it again when it updates like this:

-`main()` is the function that retrieves data from Calendar.
- `Allevents` is a list of events from the calendar. It has events appended to it within `main()`
-Other names are pretty intuitive.

```
while 1 == 1:
     time.sleep(5)
     main()
     if first == 0:
         m = set(allevents) - set(oldevents)
         print(oldevents)
         if not m:
             print('nothing changed')
         else:
             print(m)
             print("--------------------------------------------------------")
     else:
         oldevents = allevents
         first = False
     oldevents = allevents
     allevents.clear()
```

When I run this, first time it retrieves data goes perfectly: outputs `allevents` (as written in `main()`) and nothing else. The second time is when I haven't made any changes yet, so it outputs `allevents` *and* `oldevents` (which have the same values) along with a `nothing changed` message.

The third time the while loop runs is when I add an event to the calendar. In theory, I want it to output the event that I changed because of the

```
m = set(allevents) - set(oldevents)
print(oldevents)
     if not m:
         print('nothing changed')
     else:
         print(m)
         print("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

However, it follows `if not m:` and outputs `allevents` and `oldevents` with the same values and the new event that I added *and* a `nothing changed` message.

Side note: when I delete that event on the next loop, both lists remove that event as well.

The four loops(with some modifications for presentation purposes):

```
Getting the upcoming 10 events
['5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']

Getting the upcoming 10 events
['5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']
['5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']
nothing changed

Getting the upcoming 10 events
['7p4hs2ribddnl5h13erv5c1rir', '5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']
['7p4hs2ribddnl5h13erv5c1rir', '5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']
nothing changed

Getting the upcoming 10 events
['5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']
['5kt8vb1m5tad2h6higtd8seqp9']
nothing changed
```

If you think that more of the code is necessary, tell me and I will post the entire thing.

Comment: `oldevents = allevents` then  `allevents.clear()`, both oldevents and allevents are references to the same object, both will get cleared. make a copy instead, `oldevents = allevents.copy()` .[Good further read](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @Paritosh Sight thank you, I've been working at it for about two hours. Guess I need to read that link you sent me thoroughly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: No worries, its a common gotcha. Marking question as dupe for "house keeping". Check the dupe target too for some different ways to get similar results.

Answer (score 0):

in your code "first = False" sets first to zero. So it enters the if loop in next iteration.Remove "first = False" and try